# Example of a bilinear map whose image is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I am looking for an example of a bilinear map $\tau:V \times V \to W$ whose image $im(\tau)=(\tau(u,v):u,v \in V)$ is not a subspace of $W$.

I considered the tensor map $\tau:U \times V \to U \otimes V$, since its images consists of all decomposable tensors. I have the idea that if $u \otimes v, u'\otimes v'$ are decomposable tensors, then $u \otimes v + u'\otimes v'$ is not necessarily a decomposable vector, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Note that $u\otimes v + u'\otimes v$ is a decomposable tensor as $u\otimes v + u'\otimes v = (u + u')\otimes v$. However, $u\otimes v + u'\otimes v'$ may or may not be a decomposable tensor.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelAlbanese.In which cases is $u\otimes v + u'\otimes v'$ not a decomposable tensor?

Answer (score 13):

The image of $* : K[x] \times  K[y] \to K[x,y]$ contains $x$ and $y$, but not $x+y$.

Comment: Thank you. How do you define $K[x]$?

Comment: I mean the ring of polynomials over $K$ (actually, only the underlying vector space).